# Add new item to two different IDs

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this code from w3school for my own project https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_todo

How can I put the result when clicking the add button to two different ID's

```
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>

<ul id="myUL">

</ul>

<ol id="yourOL">

<ol>
```

I tried putting this inside the `newElement()` but to no avail

```
else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
    document.getElementById("yourOL").appendChild(li);
}
```

I also tried adding an onchange event in #myUl so that whatever is in the innerHTML would be the same with #yourOL but it doesn't work either.

```
<ul id="myUL" onchange="change">

</ul>

<ol id="yourOL">

<ol>

<script>
  document.getElementById("myUL").addEventListener('change', change);

  function change() {
    let guests = document.getElementById('myUL').value;
      document.getElementById('yourOL') = guests;
  } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create the element (`li`) before appending. Also in the first solution, you didn't create any function with the name `newElement`:

```js
function newElement(){
  var li = document.createElement('LI');
  li.textContent = 'some text';
  document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  var li2 = document.createElement('LI');
  li2.textContent = 'some text';
  document.getElementById("yourOL").appendChild(li2);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
    <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>

<ul id="myUL">

</ul>

<ol id="yourOL">

<ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution:

For a valid HTML do not forget to put the `myInput` value inside a `<li>`element

```js
let myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
let yourOL = document.getElementById('yourOL')
let myUL = document.getElementById('myUL')
myInput.addEventListener('change', change);

  function change() {
    let value = document.getElementById('myInput').value;    
    let guests = "<li>"+value+"</li>";
    yourOL.innerHTML += guests;
    myUL.innerHTML += guests;
   
  }
```

```html
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
            <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
            <span class="addBtn">Add</span>
 </div>

      <ul id="myUL">

      </ul>

      <ol id="yourOL">

      <ol>
```